# how to verify loadbalancing feature in Linux with KNI interfaces

Tags: testing, load-balancing, dpdk

I have a **DPDK** Based application where it load balances ingress traffic to 2 **KNI** interfaces, 
I want to verify traffic is being distributed properly (PPS) across **KNI**. Is there any mechanism/tool I can use to verify this?

Comment: What does "properly" means in your case? Approximately same bps on both paths? Same pps? All packets of a connection on the same path?

Comment: @pchaigno Approximately bps on both paths and yes, all packets are connection on the same path

Comment: Any reason you don't trust the DPDK application? Since you're sending to KNIs, I guess you could use traditional kernel tracing tools to count the number of bytes on each interface. Making sure all packet from a connection are forwarded on the same interface is going to be trickier though; you'll need to trace the TCP connection lifetime (unless you can assume there is only 1 4-tuple per connection during the lifetime of your test...).

Answer (score 0):

Use a packet generator to generate few flows to the host. If you are using Pktgen-DPDK, few flows could be generated using ranges. Just switch to `page range` and then configure min/max/inc ports and src/dst IPs as described in the Pktgen-DPDK manual: http://pktgen-dpdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands.html#runtime-options-and-commands

Once you have generated few flows for some time, just check the KNI interfaces counters with `ifconfig` of `ip` tool in Linux to make sure there are more or less even distribution among those two interfaces.